# Add Title Attribute to WordPress Image the_post_thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

i use this code to show post's thumbnail in my site but this code cant show the title Attribute of the thumbnails.

**how can i add Title Attribute to WordPress thumbnails?**

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail('large'); 
 } else {?>
<img alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/thumbnail.png"/>
<?php }?>
```

you can see my site with this url : http://rokesh.ir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that because you can add all the attributes you need:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array( 'title' => get_the_title() ) );
```

Please read on in the [Function Reference of the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).

Comment: @Chip Bennett was quicker than me. What is to do in this case? Should I delete my answer?

Answer (score 8):

As per [the Codex entry for `the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail), you can pass an attributes array as a parameter:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>
```

So you would just need to define the array; here's the Codex example, modified to include the `title` attribute:

```
$post_thumbnail_attr = array(
    'src'   => $src,
    'class' => "attachment-$size",
    'alt'   => 'alt here',
    'title' => 'title here',
);
```

...which you could then pass to `the_post_thumbnail()`:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'large', $post_thumbnail_attr );
```